# Declaring a CLICK event. ASPX vs Code behind.. how are these 2 different?

Tags: asp.net, events, click

in .ASPX this is working

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="lbHope6" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Shared/Images/Site/ChartTypeProd.png"
CssClass="chart" OnClick="lbHope6_Click" />

 protected void lbHope6_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        EventArgs args = new EventArgs();

        if (Hope6 != null)
            Hope6(this, args);
    }
```

but when I do it this way it acts differently.. any ideas?? ive given up hope

```
 LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
                lb.Text = s.Key.ToString();
                lb.Click += new EventHandler(lbHope6_Click);
                sourceNameCell.Controls.Add(lb);

   protected void lbHope6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EventArgs args = new EventArgs();

        if (Hope6 != null)
            Hope6(this, args);
    }
```

Comment: In what event are you creating the `LinkButton`?

Comment: @Dustin Laine is right - `where` you create the LinkButton (and more importantly wire-up the event) is paramount. In "old-school" ASP.NET (Web Sites), things like Page_Load and Event handlers were auto-wired up in the InitializeComponent method (called by Page_Init i believe).

Comment: How does creating that click event in the page init vs. page load affect things ? ... Right now it all happens in a function in the page_load.. it MUST happen there I think since that is where the HTML is built

Answer (score 1):

You're creating the new link button and assigning an eventhandler every time the page loads (including on postback). .Net won't understand that the LinkButton you create on postback is in fact the LinkButton you created when the page was first called. Your first code sample was fine.

Comment: its hard to explain the rest of the code aroudn it.. but basically the way it is now I need to click the link button twice for it to do what it is suppose to..

Comment: So what is the proper way to create the event programmatically?  I must do it on the page load I think because the link is made as part of a HTML table that is progarmmtically created.... So I mean its not something I can create outside that loop since inside the loop is the code that determines if that link/click event is created... that make sense?   Only other work around I could figure it to just have a seperate table containing the links and I could make that seperate table declaritivly so I could use my first technique

Comment: It all depends on how your html is generated. it's possible you are taking it the hard way. Maybe your solution is to define a DataBound ListView and use your first method to handle the clicks. The trick to get the event triggered is to construct the control on postback exactly as it was before postback in the CreateChildControls or DataBinding event.

Comment: There is no if (!IsPostBack)... so The same code is loaded bfore the click as it is loaded after the click... So that click event is subscribed to the same both ways... i dunno.. It just sucks to tell the client that this simple concept of clicking a link and it going to a page I cannot get to work.